# Sliding images with finger holding and moving in WPF, just like smartphone

Tags: wpf, xaml, sliding

This is my code:

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="1" >
     <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding Path=MyImage}"/>
 </Grid>
```

I have an image in my view, and I set its surce by binding.

Outside of this image, I have two arrows (left arrow and right). If the user clicks on the right arrow, I'm showing him the next image, if he clicks on the right arrow again - the next one, etc. This works very well.

Now I want to do it to work just like we slide images in our smartphones, by using our thumb, without using arrows. So, I need to make the images slide by clicking the mouse button, holding it and then moving it left or right.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `Behavior` that will handle the scrolling:

```
public class ScrollViewerTouchScrollBehaviour : Behavior<ScrollViewer>
    {
        private double? _horizontalOffset;
        private Point? _position;
        private double _sensitivity = 1;

        public double Sensitivity
        {
            get { return _sensitivity; }
            set { _sensitivity = value; }
        }

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
            AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseMove += PreviewMouseMove;
            AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp;
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            base.OnDetaching();
            AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown -= PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
            AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseMove -= PreviewMouseMove;
            AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp -= PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp;
        }

        private void PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _horizontalOffset = AssociatedObject.HorizontalOffset;
            _position = e.GetPosition(AssociatedObject);
        }

        private void PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            AssociatedObject.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        }

        private void PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed || !_horizontalOffset.HasValue || !_position.HasValue)
            {
                return;
            }

            var point = e.GetPosition(AssociatedObject);

            var diff = point.X / Sensitivity - _position.Value.X / Sensitivity;

            AssociatedObject.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(_horizontalOffset.Value - diff);
        }
    }
```

The `Sensitivity` property allows you to tweek the speed of the scrolling. Experiment with different values to see what best suits your application.

Then in your xaml place the content that you want to be able to scroll inside a `ScrollViewer` and add the behavior:

```
<ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <!-- Your content here -->
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviours:ScrollViewerTouchScrollBehaviour Sensitivity="1" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ScrollViewer>
```

You will of course need to add a reference to `Systems.Windows.Interactivty` in your behavior and in the xaml.

You could alternatively just handle the events in code-behind if you don't want to use a behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the mouse events on down and up and calculate the X-value

```
    private Point down;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Image_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        down = e.GetPosition(this);
    }

    private void Image_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Point up = e.GetPosition(this);
    }
```

On Image_MouseLeftButtonUp you can calculate with down.X and up.X the difference and start your actions.

Comment: Same way with touchevents.
A small hint by myself: I would prefer a small change of 20 px minimum to each side in case you don't wanted to click

Comment: But this won't show the sliding effect, it will just switch images in a second. There won't be sliding.